# Wrong pack expanded in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I got a very strange problem with variadic templates. It seems the wrong pack is expanded. Here's a code snippet:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename...>
struct types {};

template<typename = types<>>
struct Base;

template<typename... Args1>
struct Base<types<Args1...>> {
    template<typename... Args2>
    static auto construct(Args1... args1, Args2&&... args2)
        -> decltype(std::make_tuple(args1.forward()..., std::declval<Args2>()...))
    {
        return std::make_tuple(args1.forward()..., std::forward<Args2>(args2)...);
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<> {};

int main() {
    auto test = &Derived::construct<char const(&)[7]>;
}
```

I get this error:

```
13 : <source>:13:43: error: request for member 'forward' in 'args2#0', which is of non-class type 'const char [7]'
         -> decltype(std::make_tuple(args1.forward()..., std::declval<Args2>()...))
                                     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
13 : <source>:13:43: error: request for member 'forward' in 'args2#0', which is of non-class type 'const char [7]'
<source>: In function 'int main()':
22 : <source>:22:27: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '& construct<const char (&)[7]>'
     auto test = &Derived::construct<char const(&)[7]>;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
22 : <source>:22:27: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function '& construct<const char (&)[7]>'
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

However, it don't happen when the pack has values in it:

```
struct HasForward { int forward() { return 0; } };

struct Derived : Base<types<HasForward>> {};
```

Here's the <kbd>[First snippet live](https://godbolt.org/g/8T68GQ)</kbd> and the <kbd>[Second snippet live](https://godbolt.org/g/8T68GQ)</kbd>

What's wrong with this code? Is this a compiler bug? Is there any ways to overcome it and leave the first pack empty?

Comment: My clang++ compile without problem; I suppose it's a g++ bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a compiler bug? Is there any ways to overcome it and leave the first pack empty?

It looks like a bug in your compiler.
To work around it you can use a function declaration (no definition required) like the one in the following example and use it to test your parameters:

```
template<typename... Args1>
class Base<types<Args1...>> {
    template<typename... T, typename... U>
    static auto ret(types<T...>, types<U...>)
    -> decltype(std::make_tuple(std::declval<T>().forward()..., std::declval<U>()...));

public:
    template<typename... Args2>
    static auto construct(Args1... args1, Args2&&... args2)
    -> decltype(ret(types<Args1...>{}, types<Args2...>{}))
    {
        return std::make_tuple(args1.forward()..., std::forward<Args2>(args2)...);
    }
};
```

A bit ugly, but [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uhaKg6S6w29C6D0R) when your first pack is empty (also in C++11 as requested) and everything should be discarded by the linker.

--- **EDIT**

As suggested by @W.F. in the comments (thanks for the suggestion, I didn't notice it), it's even easier to accomplish that.
Just define your function as it follows:

```
static auto construct(Args1... args1, Args2&&... args2)
    -> decltype(std::make_tuple(std::declval<Args1>().forward()..., std::declval<Args2>()...))
{
    return std::make_tuple(args1.forward()..., std::forward<Args2>(args2)...);
}
```

Comment: also maybe simpler: `std::declval<Args1>().forward()...` seems to work. Tried to performed mind experiment to make the OPs code ill-formed but also failed :)

Comment: @W.F. Good point. I didn't notice it. Can I use your suggestion to integrate the answer?